# What to do if an edit war starts?

Tags: discussion, editing

Another user keeps insisting that a question about Adobe Flash player doesn't need the [adobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe) tag. The edit war is already [6 revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/449103/revisions) long.

Note that the very description of the [adobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe) tag mentions Flash player.

AFAIU Braiam is aggravated by the fact that I insisted this question was not a duplicate when he tried to revert duplicate flag I've added to another question he had answered earlier. What should we do? I am very confident that [adobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe) is a related tag.

Note also that two questions were merged, so the comments are somewhat messy.

Comment: comments have been cleaned and a link to this meta has been added.

Comment: BTW, I'm not aggravated, the other question looks too me with fairly better answers and overall quality and that has nothing to do with the fact that I removed the tag.

Comment: the one on the right is you, the one on the left is Braiam https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5iv_2Ehmws&noredirect=1 cool!

Comment: Can't view the video on GPRS network, will check it later. I'm glad that you were not aggrevated, Braiam, I hope we'll be more constructive in the future.

Comment: I've checked the video finally. Not cool.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Flag it. Never let it go that far. And that applies to both parties. This got far sillier than it needed to.

We can hopefully give a reasoned opinion and if you don't care for that, you can come to meta to discuss the contended issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is do with this:

[Do we need the Adobe, Microsoft and Apple tags?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9062/do-we-need-the-adobe-microsoft-and-apple-tags?cb=1)

I think the questions in [this list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe) are being reviewed due to the above, so it keeps being found and re-edited, creating the problem.