# Do we need the Adobe, Microsoft and Apple tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

On Ask Ubuntu we have several companies represented as tags. There are [adobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe), [microsoft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apple). I don't think these tags are useful, and perhaps they should be removed. We don't have experts on any of those companies, nor do they have something to do with with Ubuntu/Canonical. Yes they have products that run on Ubuntu, but those products already have their own tags:

- [microsoft-office](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)
- [adobe-acrobat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe-acrobat)
- [itunes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/itunes)
- [ipod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ipod)
- etc.

I don't think we need tags that encapsulate all those products. And we don't have experts in the companies themself. I think these tags don't really have a use. Should they go?

Anyone that wants to help retagging these questions can use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe+or+microsoft+or+apple). Remember, most of these questions **needs to be retagged**, not just the tag deleted.

Comment: Apple, yeah. Microsoft, yeah. Adobe? *probably*.

Comment: Yay!! Finally... I agree with @Braiam's tagging opinion :-)

Comment: Who says we do not have Adobe, Microsoft or Apple experts? I am feeling a bit offended. :)

Comment: @don.joey are you? O_O

Comment: @Seth any usage of adobe you can share? Maybe you should give a once over [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253528/clean-up-the-sony-tag-is-it-useful-at-all-or-should-we-re-tag-and-clean-up/254124#254124)

Comment: As soon as there are several products from the same company a general company tag might make sense. Just treat Microsoft and Apple the same as any other company name. There is an Nvidia or Canon tag. For example I could have a [Microsoft keyboard](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328816/microsoft-wireless-comfort-5000-or-microsoft-wireless-ergonomic-7000).

Comment: @Trilarion the entire SE [doesn't agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254124/792066): "Company tags" like microsoft or the now-defunct google were clearly useless or wrong in most situations: *tag sets like [javascript google chart] and [vba microsoft excel] were classic examples of someone trying to type out a product name complete with spaces and getting tripped up by the way tags are parsed [...].* In our case it would be the equivalent to [microsoft] [office] or [apple] [ipod].

Comment: @Braiam Okay that convinced me. Then I just want to say that there are more company tags than microsoft and apple.

Comment: @Trilarion be my guess and post questions about these tags ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, it's a good idea to check the most upvoted answers, and determine what should be done about them. I decided to check just five first, but it looks similarly after the first five.

- [adobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe)

  - [How to install adobe reader .bin download from Adobe](https://askubuntu.com/q/221416/24509) - should have [adobe-reader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe-reader) tag (and it has).
  - [Is there a way to enable commenting adobe PDF?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17031/24509) - should have [adobe-acrobat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe-acrobat) tag.
  - [Is there any useful software for filling out pdf-forms other than Adobe Reader?](https://askubuntu.com/q/32862/24509) - should have [adobe-reader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/adobe-reader) tag.
  - [Is there an open source alternative to "Adobe Digital Editions"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/118527/24509) - question for eBook reader, just gives "Adobe Digital Editions" as an example.
  - [Why did Adobe stop Flash Player for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/186779/24509) - just use [flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag.
- [microsoft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft)

  - [Problems with ttf font rendering under LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/q/181135/24509) - I decided to check the entire website, and there are lots of questions related to ttf-mscorefonts. I believe the tag for these should be created.
  - [Is Live Video Chat with MSN/Windows possible?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2554/24509) - just use [msn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/msn) tag.
  - [Unable to change the Flash microphone settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/232080/24509) - I don't even know why it uses [microsoft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft).
  - [How can I get media keys working on my keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72562/24509) - should use [microsoft-keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-keyboard).
  - [Is dual booting the answer, or separate OS per device?](https://askubuntu.com/q/346445/24509) - question about dual booting with Windows 8. It uses [windows-8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) tag.
- [apple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apple)

  - [How do I switch the Command key and Control key on a MacBook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/q/131900/24509) - this is about hardware, and there is [macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook) tag.
  - [Is there a way to stream audio/video to an Apple Airplay Device?](https://askubuntu.com/q/30794/24509) - [itunes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/itunes) is already used.
  - [What is the current state of apple device (iPhone, iPod, etc.) support?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83484/24509) - question about [ios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ios).
  - [How can share my printer so that I can use it with Airprint?](https://askubuntu.com/q/26130/24509) - question about [ios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ios).
  - [ubuntu å vs osx å?](https://askubuntu.com/q/335712/24509) - interoperation of Mac OS X and Ubuntu Linux. Should just have [macosx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macosx).

Most of those (there is a possibility I missed something) can be categorized in more specific categories. Therefore, I believe that those tags don't add extra value, and should be replaced with more specific tags.

Comment: I agree with most you have said, just with slights variants: keyboard-layout questions (make X key print X character) should use the keyboard-layout tag. There's a microsoft-keyboard tag. Manufacturers are normally bad tag, in fact this question is about them, the question about multimedia keyboard should use the microsoft-keyboard/shortcut-keys tag. Just me being me, but I think you will agree.

Comment: I have been thinking about this for quite some time and I agree that the tags are too general. BTW: congrats on a good meta answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the Open Source shop I volunteer in http://freegeek.org we repair Apple hardware, and a number of folks have us put Xubuntu and other 'buntu distros on non-Macbook Macs. Therefore, I do suggest the Apple tag has a place because folks do run Linux on Apple hardware.

Comment: This doesn't mean that there isn't a more specific tag applicable to the question (at the very least [tag:mac]).

Answer (score -11):

**NO** we don't need them.  In fact, we should change the name of like `Microsoft-Office` Tag to like `C**p-Office` And the `iPod` tag chance it to like `Jail-Locked-MP3-Player`  Just joking... I totally agreed with you [Braiam](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/169736/braiam) We don't need them or tags like `itunes` which can go under `wine` tag or we can created a tag like `wine-application` or `nonnative-application` tag which them all the question for wine like how can configure it can go under the `wine tag`.

Comment: Renaming itunes to wine would not be intuitive to users unaware of wine.

Comment: @Jobin True....  Didn't think of that

Comment: I agree we shouldn't need the tags, but I don't like your other ideas so much.

Comment: @seth Why don't you like the other ideas?

Comment: @Andrew On second thought, I'm not so sure anymore.. Let me think about it a bit.

Comment: Well, the Office is one of the reasons why I don't hate Microsoft. If other products were of the same quality, Ubuntu would become the second Haiku. However your idea about itunes makes sence.

Comment: Office is the ONLY reason I still use Microsoft (on a VM) If I could figure out how to move my heavily modified customer-centric Access Database to a Linux alternative, I would dump that as well. Apologies.. this seems off-topic now that I look at it.

Comment: @ElderGeek You need a alternative to Access?

Comment: @Andrew I do indeed want an alternative to Access, that I can import my existing customer, inventory, billing data into.